# Is there a way to perform calculations with two lists together in Python?

Tags: python, list

For example, if I want values in list a to multiply with values of the same position in list B :

A = [1,2,3]
B = [4,5,6]
Then the desired calculations are:
1 multiplied by 4, 2 multiplied by 5 and  3 multiplied by6

Comment: If any answer here helped you, please consider [accepting it](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/179419). This indicates that the issue is resolved, and helps others find the correct answer more easily.

Answer (score 2):

Iterate through two lists at a time using the `zip` function.

```
A = [1, 2, 3]
B = [4, 5, 6]
C = []

for a, b in zip(A, B):
    C.append(a*b)
    
print(C)
# Prints [4, 10, 18]
```

Answer (score 2):

Using list comprehension (faster than for loop):

```
>>> res_list = [ls1[i] * ls2[i] for i in range(len(ls1))]
```

OR

Numpy (fastest method) :

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> ls1 = np.array([1,2,3,4])
>>> ls2 = np.array([2,1,6,5])
>>> res = ls1 * ls2
>>> print(res)
array([2,3,18,20])
```

OR

for loop (slowest but easily readable) :

```
res= []
for i in range(len(a)):
     res.append(ls1[i]*ls2[i]) 
print(res)
```

Edit:
Kindly check this speed performance graph from [freeCodeCamp](https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/if-you-have-slow-loops-in-python-you-can-fix-it-until-you-cant-3a39e03b6f35/)

[image]

Comment: "Using list comprehension (faster than for loop)" list comprehensions are only marginally more performant than a loop, and as the work you do on each iteration increases that performance disappeared, list comprehensions aren't really for performance but for readability

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga Acc. to the graph using listcomp makes the code run more than 50% faster than with a for loop

Comment: Right, because *multiplication* is a very fast thing. The optimizations for a list-comprehension are basic, avoiding the method resolution of `resulting_list.append` and a small stack-based bytecode optimization. You can even "cache" the method resolution by using `append = resulting_list.append` and using `append(whatever)` in a loop. Just that is enough to make the difference almost disappears. And again, as the work you do in the list comprehension increases, it becomes practically no difference.

Comment: For example, for `timeit.timeit('comp(A,B)', 'from __main__ import A, B, comp, loop', number=10_000)` I'm getting `12.15388411699999`, for `timeit.timeit('loop(A,B)', 'from __main__ import A, B, comp, loop', number=10_000)` with the "method caching" trick I mentioned, I'm getting `15.503835907000052` where `A = [1, 2, 3] * 10_000` and `B = [4, 5, 6] * 10_000`

Comment: That is a pretty terrible article, btw.

Answer (score 1):

If you're looking for a one-liner, you can use list comprehension for this:

```py
C = [x*y for x, y in zip(A, B)]
```

---

**References:**

- [`zip()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#zip)
- [List comprehension](https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_lists_comprehension.asp)

Answer (score 1):

Here are two ways to do it:

The more "Pythonic" way to do it is list comprehension:

```
A = [1, 2, 3]
B = [4, 5, 6]
C = [a * b for a, b in zip(A, B)] # [4, 10, 18]
```

Another way is to iterate on both of the lists with the function `zip()`:

```
A = [1, 2, 3]
B = [4, 5, 6]
C = []
for a,b in zip(A, B):
    result = a * b
    C.append(result)
# C = [4, 10, 18]
```

Good Luck!